# How to access a shadowed file-level property in the src package

Tags: android, kotlin

```
val a = "Hi"

fun main() {
    val a = 5
    println(a)
}
```

Assuming I put this directly into a kt file in the **src** package. How do I access the top-level `a` inside the function?

Answer (score 0):

The top level variables are put into the package namespace.
So you need to use `packagename.toplevelvariable`.
In your case use `src.a` inside the `main` function in order to access the top level `a`.
By the way, if you want to put your file in the `src` package, you need to add `package src` at the top of the file.